# bootstrap 4 plugins - method they are registered in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-plugins, bootstrap-4

Reading the bootstrap 4 code (how they register pluging in jquery) I can't understand several lines:

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/js/src/tooltip.js

1) Why author add to method Tooltip._jQueryInterface the `Constructor` property ? What kind of functionalyt they try to provide with that?

```
  $.fn[NAME] = Tooltip._jQueryInterface // this is clear
  $.fn[NAME].Constructor = Tooltip  // mmmmm ?
```

2) what is done there (added noConflict method, but how it will be used?):

```
  $.fn[NAME].noConflict = function () {
    $.fn[NAME] = JQUERY_NO_CONFLICT
    return Tooltip._jQueryInterface
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Now I know the answer on question two (wth is `$.fn[NAME].noConflict = function () {..}`).

According to https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#js-noconflict

This plugins `noconflict` method can be used such way:

```
var bootstrapButton = $.fn.button.noConflict() // return $.fn.button to previously assigned value
$.fn.bootstrapBtn = bootstrapButton            // give $().bootstrapBtn the Bootstrap functionality
```